# String input not working correctly

Tags: java, string, input

All I am trying to do is write code to ask the user for a sequence of numbers separated by spaces.

It should be simple, and to my (admittedly limited) knowledge, the following code should work just fine:

```
    System.out.print("How many numbers? ");
    int n = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Please enter " + n + " numbers (seperated by spaces) ");
    String numbers = input.nextLine();
```

Except it isn't working. I input the integer for n, then when the program asks me to input a sequence of numbers, I can't type anything in at all, letters, numbers, anything.

This is how far it gets:

```
How many numbers? 8
Please enter 8 numbers (seperated by spaces)
```

and while it should be accepting my next input into the String variable numbers, it is certainly not doing so.

Comment: are you sure that nextInt removes the newline character after parsing the int?

Comment: I have no idea what this even means. I am in an intro java course, and I don't even think we have talked about that. Unless of course our very Asian professes mentioned it in passing and I didn't catch it

Comment: You should tag your questions with the correct language tag to get better results.  ie is this java?

Comment: So I googled it, and indeed that newline thing was the issue. Thank you @BeyelerStudios

Answer (score 0):

In your case when you `enter` after first input, it takes it as new line so add another `readline` to eliminate that case

```
        System.out.print("How many numbers? ");
        int n = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Please enter " + n + " numbers (seperated by spaces) ");
        String numbers = input.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should parse line inputs as whole lines:

```
int n;
for(boolean read = false; !read; ) {
    System.out.print("How many numbers? ");
    String line = input.nextLine();
    // parse line to n and set read on success
    // one possibility (not the only way)
    try {
        n = Integer.parseInt(line);
        read = true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("\"" + line + "\" is not an integer");
    }
}
for(boolean read = false; !read; ) {
    System.out.print("Please enter " + n + " numbers (seperated by spaces) ");
    String line = input.nextLine();
    int parsedInts = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i, ++parsedInts) {
        // try to parse the next int from line and break on failure
        ...
    }
    read = parsedInts == n;
}
```